# Linux: AWK in line

Tags: linux, command

Hopefully anyone can help me changing the code below, my tempfile  consists of the code:

```
Temp=8.4*  Humidity=70.4%
```

instead of the code

```
Temp = 24 *C, Hum = 40 %
```

which works for below script.

I need 8.4 as Temp=# and 70.4 as HUM=#

```
TEMP=$(cat $TMPFILE|grep Temp |awk '{print $3}')
if [ $TEMP ]
then
TEMP=$(cat $TMPFILE|grep Temp |awk '{print $3}')
HUM=$(cat $ $TMPFILE |grep Temp |awk '{print $7}')
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

No need for `awk`, use parameter expansion in bash:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

read temp hum < $tmpfile
temp=${temp#Temp=}    # Remove from left.
temp=${temp%\*}       # Remove from right.
hum=${hum#Humidity=}
hum=${hum%\%}
```